# ExpressJS res.cookie mismatch in maxAge and expires

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying to set 10-years expiration for a cookie in my ExpressJS app:

```js
res.cookie('sessionId', session.sessionId, {
  sameSite: 'Lax',
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: 10*365*24*60*60*1000,
})
```

However, my cookie only lasts 36 days, instead of 10 years. When I was trying to figure out why, I saw that this is what Chrome shows on the Network tab:

[image: Network tab]

There are two issues:

- Expires is being set (although I did not ask for) - strangely, it is set correctly (today + 10 years)
- Max-Age is being set to a different value than I'm asking for in my source code

What is the correct way to achieve a 10-year expiration cookie?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a cookie with 10 years max-age in Chrome now.
[Cookie Expires and Max-Age attributes now have upper limit](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/cookie-max-age-expires/)

About your 2 issues, I'm not sure why

Comment: Got it, however still unclear why maxAge and expires are being set inconsistently by ExpressJS. Any idea how to solve it?